# Generate a 10-digit random number

Tags: matlab, random

I want to generate a random number with exactly 10-digits.

The random number cannot begin with zero, i.e. it must be a 10 digit number, not 10 random digits.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Add some code to your question and show us what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 3):

You need a random integer, between `1000000000` (the lowest integer with 10 digits) and `9999999999` (the highest number with 10 digits).

Note that `1000000000 = 1e9` and `9999999999 = 1e10 - 1`

The random integer generation can easily achieved with `randi` (see the documentation [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html)), giving it the correct minimum and maximum values...

```
n = randi([1e9, 1e10-1])
```